# set different background colors to partials based on database value

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

Trying to make different colors for different partials based on their `type`; so far there are 3 types all defined by an integer `1`, `2` or `3` and I am struggling to find a way to make the partials in the view appear with different background colors. I am trying to get *Red* for `1`, *Blue* for `2`, *Green* for `3`. I have tried multiple things but none have seemed to work.

I've tried making `before_action :set_colours`, having `if` statements in the partial but nothing has worked so far.

Here is the *html*, calling the `type` would be done like `o.type`

```
<div class="dropdown" style="background-color: <%= set_background(number) %>;">
  <button class="btn  btn-block" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton"
   data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <%=o.id%>, <%=o.user_id%> 
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu btn-block" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item">Order Type</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item"> Event type:</a> <p><%=o.event_type%></p></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item"> Requirements/Ideas</a> <p><%=o.description%></p></li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a helper that will return the color you need based on the type, for example:

```
def set_background_color(type)
  case type
  when 1 then "red"
  when 2 then "blue"
  when 3 then "green"
  end
end
```

And then use it to set the background color of your `div` using the `style` attribute, like this:

```
<div class="dropdown" style="background-color: <%= set_background_color(o.type) %>;">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!